# virtualbox machine inaccessible after drive letter change. Can I change the drive letter of a VM?

Tags: virtualbox

I have a USB drive, it was E, now it's F.

Virtualbox VMs point to E, and say inaccessible

[image]

I know I could change my external drive letter's drive letter from F to E and it should be fine, but I want to be able to fix this within virtualbox, either in the virtualbox GUI or command line or editing a virtualbox vm configuration file.

If I right click the VM, settings is greyed out

So I see no option to change from E to F

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VirtualBox keeps a registry of the VMs you've created/imported.  This registry is just an XML file that can be edited.  The file is located at:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml
```

In this file there is a section called `MachineRegistry` that lists all of your VMs:

```
<MachineRegistry>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx}" src="E:\virtualbox\Ubuntu 14.04  LTS\Ubuntu 14.04  LTS.vbox"/>
</MachineRegistry>
```

Just updated the paths in this file.

Comment: I don't have that xml file. What version is yours? Here is a screenshot of mine showing version http://i.imgur.com/8T9Jx7J.png    and here are the files , no xml file there

Comment: I'm using 5.0, but this file has existed in the 4.x version as well.

Comment: and here's the directory with the VMs, no xml file http://pastebin.com/2nxBZFGZ

Comment: Yes, this isn't the VM directory you can set in the settings, which is what that directory listing is.

Comment: Here is the main program directory but I don't see it there either, no xml files http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=pRVEu2Wp

Comment: That link isn't working for me.  Did you check the directory I gave you?  Its not the program directory or the VM directory, its data directory inside your User Profile directory.